# How to resolve NoSuchElement exception in selenium?

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, nosuchelementexception

I had one link initially. Now I received the requirement of showing button instead of a link for A/B testing. I have to make their ids same since I don't want to write a new test for the button.

To decide which to display I added two unique classes in the `li` item. This is working fine.

But on testing it starts failing, giving the message "Subscriber link is not available" although button is present there.

I thought that it might failing because of two same ids are there so i added two same classes and change the selector from id to class. But it still failing.

```
<li class="not_subscriber subscriber-text-link " style="display:none">
  <a class="link-orange subscribe" href="" id="subscribe_link"> Subscribe </a>
</li>
<li class="not_subscriber subscriber-orange-btn " style="display:none">
  <a class="btn-orange subscribe" href=""  id="subscribe_link" > Subscribe </a>
</li>

@FindBy(css = ".subscribe")
@NoSuchElementDescription("Subscriber link is not available")
protected WebElement _subscribeLink;
```

Is there any way such that i dont have to write new test and change ids and test will start passing??

Comment: Share your code. Your list items are starting with display:none. Can't say much without seeing your code.

Comment: a file which runs on all pages , there based on a optimizely variable i am setting display 'block' of one li item. problem is Button is visible while running the code but still it can't find it. code is very long.

Comment: From the code you have shown, you are finding the element by class = subscribe. If you put that class on your button it should work.

Comment: already added in link and button as well. see anchor tag above.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try below Xpath:-

```
//li[@class='not_subscriber subscriber-orange-btn ']/a[@class='btn-orange subscribe']
```

Hope it will help you :)

Answer (score -1):

Change the selector to xpath. Almost every element has an xpath. And be sure to replace the double quotes to single quotes. It should be more reliable than class or id selectors.

Comment: XPath is not more reliable than class or id. XPath is slower and depending on how you craft them, more brittle than other methods.

Comment: How Xpath is more reliable than ID selector, any supporting link/doc?

Comment: By reliable I meant you should be able to find an xpath on every element. It's just my opinion from my own experience using Selenium, no supporting docs.